# Sharing state across multiple namespaces

Tags: clojure

Programming my first Clojure program I stumbled across the following task, which I cannot solve :

```
(ns core
  (:require [calc]))

(def data 1) 
(calc/updatedata)
data 
;; should return 2

(ns calc)
(refer 'core :only '[data]) 
(defn updatedata []
  (def data (+ 1 data)))
```

Now I have two problems:

- As `core` requires `calc`, `calc` gets invoked first but then there is no symbol `data` to refer to yet. I have no idea how to get around that :(
- I cannot redefine `data` with `def`, getting the error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: data already refers to #'core/data in namespace: calc`. Maybe I should use a ref/atom/agent here (haven't worked with those yet but I am looking into it now..)?

How can I refer and mutate `core/data` in `calc` as if it was defined there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an extension to what RedDeckWins proposed, if you wish let the mutation happen in `core` and avoid passing `data` to every function in `calc`, you could create a dynamic var in `calc`. The very first statement in `update-data`, you would bind the passed in value to the dynamic var. All concerned functions in `calc` would always refer to the dynamic var.

```
(ns noob-1.calc)

(def ^:dynamic *app-data* {:val false})

(defn action-1 []
  (println "action-1 data - " *app-data*))

(defn action-2 []
  (println "action-2 data - " *app-data*))

(defn actions [data]
  (binding [*app-data* data]
    (println "actions data - " *app-data*)
    (action-1)
    (action-2)
    (assoc *app-data* :val "2")))
```

---

```
(ns noob-1.core
  :require [noob-1.calc :as calc])

(def app-data (atom {:val "1"}))

(defn calc-stuff []
  (swap! app-data calc/actions))
```

That said, I would still recommend passing `app-data` to each function in `calc`. That way, each function can incrementally modify `app-data` and `actions` can return the final state. To support mutations and avoid passing state to each function, you would need to replace the dynamic var with an atom. The atom in `calc` will be used locally and its value returned from `actions`. I would avoid that.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my questions :)
In addition I found this interesting article which explains some of the problems with the dynamic var approach (the best explanation I could find so far!): http://stuartsierra.com/2013/03/29/perils-of-dynamic-scope

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you are doing this completely incorrectly and probably have a fundamental misunderstanding of how you should program in Clojure, but here we go.

```
(ns clojure-scratch.core
  (:require [clojure-scratch.calc :as calc]))

(def data (atom 1))

(swap! data calc/update-data)
```

in the other file

```
(ns clojure-scratch.calc)

(defn update-data [n]
  (inc n))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Maybe I oversimplified my example. Actually the update-data function includes many other functions, which all depend on the data. So, as I am working on only one set of data, instead of passing it down the whole chain I wanted to be able to refer to it from anywhere inside the code, thats why I wanted to refer to it. Are there no usecases where one would prefer this "global state" behaviour to "passing the state" to almost all functions?
For example assume the data was a central config in the `core` ns, which I want to mutate in an `options-menu` ns.

Comment: Thinking more about it, I like the idea of having the mutation (`swap!`) only appear in the `core` namespace, as there are no side-effects from elsewhere in the code. But this still leaves me with the problem of passing the data/config through all called functions in the `calc` namespace.. How would you tackle that? Is bindings the way to go here?

Comment: Well if it was me I would just pass the data and config along.  Your other options are to defonce the config, assuming it doesn't change, and then just refer to it wherever you need.